Weight painting having too much influence and clunky
I'm no expert and in fact I did have a nice transition on a couple of my early weight paints, but I must have done something because now the mesh is reacting very strangely to the weight paint.




We're going to need more info here. What does "reacting strangely" mean? What are you aiming for? What does "working correctly" look like to you? Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Thank you for your timely reply.  It's just  weird how the very weak weight paint is excerting full control and completely shifting entire blocks of vertices, whereas when I auto weight meta rigs its a nice gradual transition (more elastic)

I did reply to this thread with a scene file and additional information, I don't know why I can't see it here.  But I re-rigged the character with a base bones and more other bones and it appears to be working better with auto weighting but one random bone is moving the entire mesh.  I will investigate further.
